# 2 ntds.dit files in Windows Server 2008 R2 and Active Directory logging

Tags: logging, active-directory, windows-server-2008

Why is there 2 files named ntds.dit. 
**C:\Windows\NTDS\ntds.dit** and **C:\Windows\System32\ntds.dit**? Is there any difference between them?
Another question, are changes to AD written to edb.log are equivalent to entries stored in **System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to the question from MS technet site:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/91ef5845-e5f7-470e-ae26-a8bb3e69c4f9/2-ntdsdit-files-in-windows-server-2008-r2-and-active-directory-logging

citation:

> Not sure what the file NTDS.DIT is doing within the
>   C:\Windows\System32\ folder it is probably a skeleton file (I am just
>   guessing).  The NTDS folder holds your Directory Service info.
>
> Security.evtx is your security event log
>
> edb.log is your transaction log for Directory Services.  Changes are
>   added to this log file and then they are updated in AD.  If there is a
>   failure midway thorugh on your DC there is a way to either back the
>   change out or be able to complete it when the DC is rebooted.  This is
>   basically your transaction log file

Answer (score 1):

Active Directory data is stored in the Ntds.dit ESE database file. Two copies of Ntds.dit are present in separate locations on a given domain controller:
***%SystemRoot%\NTDS\Ntds.dit***    This file stores the database that is in use on the domain controller. It contains the values for the domain and a replica of the values for the forest (the Configuration container data).
***%SystemRoot%\System32\Ntds.dit***    This file is the distribution copy of the default directory that is used when you promote a Windows 2000 – based computer to a domain controller. The availability of this file allows you to run the Active Directory Installation Wizard (Dcpromo.exe) without your having to use the Windows 2000 Server operating system CD. During the promotion process, Ntds.dit is copied from the %SystemRoot%\System32 directory into the %SystemRoot%\NTDS directory. Active Directory is then started from this new copy of the file, and replication updates the file from other domain controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Ntds.dit is the main AD database file. NTDS stands for NT Directory Services. The DIT stands for Directory Information Tree. The Ntds.dit file on a particular domain controller contains all naming contexts hosted by that domain controller, including the Configuration and Schema naming contexts.

We can locate the file in :
 `C:\Windows\NTDS\ntds.dit`